# Windows, WSH: Open a random available port?

Tags: windows, networking, scripting, port, wsh

How can I open random free (available) port on Windows, using Windows Scripting Host? Preferably JavaScript.

There's the "HNetCfg" object, but I couldn't find any official docs for it (MSDN?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass zero as the port parameter.